# How can I get exchange email subfolders on my Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: email, outlook, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Does anyone know how I can access exchange email subfolders on my Samsung Galaxy S3?

I have set my Samsung Galaxy S3 up with my corporate exchange 2010 server and it syncs all the inbox emails, calender appointments, and contacts without problem but I cant access any of my email subfolders.

This device is running Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there all along!

Open up the email app and press the menu button.

Go to View>Folders

You now need to tap the folder icon next to Inbox and it will 'expand' and display all the subfolders under it.

This MUST be the icon and not the text. It wont work if you press the text so you must press the icon.

I have to say this is pretty poor UI design, as it is not obvious to end users.

I'll try and add a screenshot when I next get the s3.

Comment: Dammit Samsung..