# How can I display Exchange sub folders with the native mail application?

Tags: email, exchange

I have multiple sub folders that have email routed them via rules. Is there a way to get these folders on my phone so they show new messages as they come in the same way my Inbox does? I know the 3rd party application Touchdown works really well but was hoping that I could just use the native mail application on the phone.

Comment: How are you accessing your mails? IMAP? POP3? Outlook?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that, we are using Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer - This [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25232) shows how to open subfolders on the Galaxy S3. But it doesn't work on my Galaxy Advance with Android 2.3.6. The native mail app seems only to display top level folders. K9 works better.