# Some mail subfolders not syncing

Tags: exchange, stock-email-app

I have a new issue which just started where not all subfolders are appearing in the Mail app. Almost all subfolders are present, except for those that are part of a particular folder.

I'm running 4.3 on a Samsung Galaxy III, connecting to an MS Exchange server.

Everything appears normal in the Desktop client and Web client.

I realize this could be an Exchange question, but has anyone else run into this issue and are there any suggestions? It it possible this is a size issue related to the overall size of this particular folder?

Note: [How can I get exchange email subfolders on my Samsung Galaxy S3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/how-can-i-get-exchange-email-subfolders-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s3) did not help me.

Comment: As "stock email app" varies from device to device, it might help to name yours, as well as the mail server(s) involved (as you mention exchange, probably an MS Exchange server? Or are others affected as well?).

Answer (score 0):

Try a different App?

K9-Mail is pretty good.